# Config Spec to display labeled files from 2 branches

Tags: clearcase, config-spec

I have 2 branches

1) `/main/branch1_tv` - `<vob>/se/ip/FolderA, folderB`...

2) `/main/branch1_tv/branch2_tv` - `<vob>/se/ip/FolderC`

I have created a Label [Label_1_tv]. What i want to do is have one config spec that will display all the labled folders and files in it in 1 view.

Notes: CC 7.1.1. `Branch1` is off of `Main/0`.
`branch 2` is off of `/main/0` and `/branch1/0`.
I have labeled all the elements in `branch 1` from the VOB level and `FolderC` and all its elements.

I think this will help by being able to display elements from several locations in 1 view and make building and developing easier.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

First, the easiest thing is to test your config spec in a dynamic view: it is much quicker to change a config spec and update (almost instantly) the content of a dynamic view as opposed to a snapshot view.

Then all you need is a set of selection rules like (for seeing one label):

```
cd m:\view1
cleartool edcs
<edit the config spec with>
element * .../branch1/Label_1_tv
element * /main/LATEST
```

Note the `.../branch1/LATEST` syntax: you don't need to care from which branch (`/main` or otherwise) `branch1` is coming from.

See "[How a config spec works](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.tutorial.doc/a_how_configspec_works.htm) for more.
"[Config spec rules for elements in subbranches](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.tutorial.doc/a_config_rules_subbranch.htm)" can be of interest for `Branch2`.

If you want to see *both* labels, the *order* of the rules is important:

```
element * .../branch2/Label_2_tv
element * .../branch1/Label_1_tv
element * /main/LATEST
```

For any given version:

- you select first `Label_2_tv` in `branch2`,
- if there is no `Label_2_tv` or `branch2`, then you try and select `Label_1_tv` in `branch1`.
- if not, as a fallback rule, you select `main/LATEST` (there always at least one version on branch `main`)