# Config spec in ClearCase

Tags: clearcase, config, cleartool, specifications

I have tiny question about ClearCase. Help me please! When does config spec start to work? When I click CHECK OUT or CHECK IN ? I have `test.c` and I have config spec

```
element * CHECKEDOUT
element * .../branch_1/LATEST
element * /main/LATEST -mkbranch branch_1
```

then I modify `test.c`, then I change config spec:

```
element * CHECKEDOUT
element * .../branch_2/LATEST
element * /main/LATEST -mkbranch branch_2
```

Then I Check in `test.c` and I have: created `/main/branch_1/1`. BUT WHY???

Answer (score 3):

The config spec will apply the rules on each update and on checkout, and on checkin (but not as you think it would).

On checkin, the new version will be created in the branch it has been checked out (here **`branch_1`**).
That new version might not be *selected* by the new config spec, BUT the branch in which it has been checked out is NOT changed by said new config spec.

Changing `branch1` in `branch2` while `test.c` is *already* checked out (in `branch1`) doesn't change anything. It will be checked in in `branch_1`.

Now that you will create a version on `branch1` on checkin for `test.c` (even with your second config spec), you need to realize that all future checkout/checkins will take place on that same branch for `test.c`, because:

- the rule `element * branch_1/LATEST` will keep the new versions on that branch
- the rule `element * /main/LATEST -mkbranch branch_2` is only valid for version checked out from main (and test.c is no longer on `/main`, it is on `branch1`: `/main/branch1`)

This config spec would make sure that all new versions (after the first checkin of `test.c` on `branch1`)  are done on `branch2`:

```
element * CHECKEDOUT
element * .../branch_2/LATEST
element * ../branch_1/LATEST  -mkbranch branch_2
element * /main/LATEST -mkbranch branch_2
```

The *order* of the rules is important, because the first one that can be applied "wins" (i.e. the pothers are ignored).
See this concrete example of config spec in "[Config Spec to display labeled files from 2 branches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8735144/6309)".

---

Note that after the first checkin of `test.c`, you will get a new version created on `branch1`, as explained before.

Yet your second config spec will select `/main/1`, not `/main/branch1/1`.

That is because of an incorrect rule in your second config spec:

```
element * branch_1/LATEST
```

This one would select the right version:

```
element * .../branch_1/LATEST
```

But if your second config spec has no rule regarding `branch1`, `test.c` will still be selected as `/main/1`: there is no version created on `branch2`, so `element * /main/LATEST` is the *only* rule that can be applied.

Comment: Thank you very much! I am an absolute beginner, and it is hard for me. i do not understand "Changing branch1 in branch2 while test.c is already checked out (in branch1) doesn't change anything. It will be checked in in branch_1.". when I do check out test.c again what will be chosen on view?

Comment: @all the *second* checkout will be done according to the current config spec (that you have modified), so it will be still `branch1` (because only LATEST of main are to be checked out in `branch2`). If you want top see branch2 on the second checkout, you need an additional selection rule: `element * .../branch1/LATEST -mkbranch branch2`, put in second position.

Comment: @all no problem, I have edited my answer to add some other elements for explanation.

Comment: ok! thank you! I do this things into ClearCase and I have a result: created /main/branch_1/1, but selected /main/1 . I need help) I understand (thank you!!!:) ) that was created /main/branch_1/1 , but why do I see in tree /main/1 "reserved" ?

Comment: @all you mean during the second checkout? Note that reserved is set on a version which has no number in it. So in your case, a version created from `/main/1`, but not `/main/1` itself.

Comment: I am sorry, may be I say no correctly. My task: I have Conf Spec (1). ClearCase object test.c selected by view has /main/1 version. User has enough rights for branc_1 and branch_2. What will happen after the following command sequence is executed? 1. check out test.c 2. modify test.c 3. change Config Spec (2). 5. check in test.c . In result I have: created /main/branch_1/1 version of test.c and selected /main/1 version. And I do not understand it((

Comment: I made mistake in second config spec! I have tiny question about ClearCase. Help me please! When does config spec start to work? When I click CHECK OUT or CHECK IN ? I have test.c and I have config spec

element * CHECKEDOUT
element * .../branch_1/LATEST
element * /main/LATEST -mkbranch branch_1
then I modify test.c, then I change config spec:

element * CHECKEDOUT
element * .../branch_2/LATEST
element * /main/LATEST -mkbranch branch_2
Then I Check in test.c and I have: created /main/branch_1/1. AND celected /main/1 version again. BUT WHY???

Comment: @all I believe my answer has all the answer you need.

Comment: @all note that you can edit your question. Read also attentively http://stackoverflow.com/about

Comment: @all my latest edit answer your revised question. See the last four lines.