# How to checkout multiple times using different branches for the same element inside same view of Clearcase

Tags: clearcase

How do I checkout different branches of the same element in the same view by modifying the config_spec accrodingly in Clearcase?
Clearexplorer is giving message that already another version is checkedout in the same view, even though I have selected another branch in the config_spec rule correctly.
Any clue will help me.
Thank you.

Comment: Can you copy the exact error message in your question?

Comment: I have edited my answer according to your screenshots

Answer (score 0):

The view is set to select only one version at a time.

If you want to checkout in another branch *using the same view*, you would always get the error message stating that the file is already checked out in the current view.

You can try change the config spec in order to:

- select a non-checked out version of the file
- make sure the checkout will create a new branch

But even in that case, ClearCase might refuse to check out twice that file in *the same view*.

Don't forget the selection rules in the config spec are read from top to bottom: the first one which can be applied applies.

So when you say "I have selected another branch in the config_spec rule correct", make sure that rule is in the top.
But I don't believe the error message will be different.

That issue is different from "[How to Checkout (reserved) an element that is already checked out (reserved) in another view](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21129391)", where the solution is simply to checkout  unreserved.

---

As your screenshot shows (from the position of the "eye"), your config spec select:

- checked out version first
- `/main/LATEST`

You would need to put a selection rule at the top of your config spec in order to:

- select LATEST of app_build_changes

That is:

```
element * .../app_build_changes/LATEST
element * /main/LATEST -mkbranch app_build_changes
element /main/0 -mkbranch app_build_changes
```

But since:

- the very first rule would still be element * CHECKEDOUT
- you already have a CHECKEDOUT version

Your other rules would *still* be ignored, and the eye would still select the version you show in the first screenshot.

In short: use another dynamic view.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Hello,
I added the VERSION TREE Picture where it shows that another CHECKEDOUT element is UNRESERVED mode. So, checkout on another branch of the same element in the same dynamic view fails with the message that another element version is already checkedout.

Error Message is also attached by creating another UNRESERVED CHECKOUT as shown.
[image]

Comment: Thank you. I meant editing your question, not adding "an answer" (which isn't an answer)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using 
**element * CHECKEDOUT**  rule in the config_spec,

if I change it to

**element *  /main/CHECKEDOUT**     -- one time when I am in main trunk

**element * /main/*app_build_changes*/CHECKEDOUT**  -- another time when I am in branch

Then also it doesn't check out and gives me the same error of duplicate checkout in the same view.

Comment: Please stop adding "answer": you can edit your question.

Comment: And consider that the config spec *order* is important: so that won't work. See for instance http://stackoverflow.com/a/16001035/6309