# Rename CCRC label to an existing label name to merge code

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-remote-client

In CCRC we have a "**MainBranch**" from main Branch we took a branch named "**branch1**" with label "**label1**" and we started checking into that.

The main branch also having a label with the **same label name "label1**".So we created another label "**label2**" in the same branch "**branch1**" and checked in some code into that.

Is it possible to rename "label1" to "label2" in branch1 **without affecting the codes in "mainBranch**" ? so that we will get the entire codes under same label. If any other way to solve this issue please suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A label references a collection of ClearCase versions (files and directories), and is used in a (CCRC web view) config spec [(like this one)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16001035/6309) to start a branch.
It should be immutable (meaning the content it references should *never* change)

So you cannot renaming an existing label without affecting an existing views, with version created in `branch1` from `label1` which would  no longer be visible/accessible after renaming the label `label2`.

Simply keep working in `branch1` as it is defined, or merge `branch1` in `MainBranch`, then create a new label and a new branch from there.